# testing statistical significance when comparing regression models

Tags: regression, statistics, random-forest, xgboost, model-evaluations

I have 3 models, a random forest, a XGBoost and a baseline regression model. I've performed a 5-fold cross validation on all models and use MAE as the scoring metric. So this means I basically have 3 MAE values to compare. My question is: How do I (statistically) test if and which model performs better? I've read that one should use a paired non parametric test but when there are enough data points one can assume normal distribution for the sample population (central limit theorem). I'm not sure which test to use, could someone please explain this to me?